# Updating column in table using left join from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I want to update column 'location_cost' under 'animals' table basis cost stated under 'location_costs' table. Primary key is location to join both tables. I have tried the following code but it gives me syntax error.

```
//UPDATE animals.* 
SET animals.location_cost = location_costs.costs
FROM animals       
LEFT JOIN location_costs
ON animals.location = location_costs.location;//
```

> Error: syntax error at or near "SET"
> SET animals.location_cost = location_costs.costs

I am attaching a picture which gives an idea for the tables and columns here:

[Tables View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj5i4.jpg)

I am not able to decipher the error and would appreciate if someone can help me with this code.

Thank you.

Comment: `update animals` not `update anmials.*` - But Postgres you should not repeat the target table in the FROM clause and the way you are doing it, creates a cross join of the `animals` table with itself because there is no "join condition" between the target table and the one in the FROM clause.

Comment: i used update animals initially- which gave me the error: table name "animals" specified more than once (duplicate alias) .You are right on the repetition of tables creating an error, how do i fix that? Thank you for responding.

Comment: Is there a foreign key in the animals table that references the location column of the location_cost table? What is the primary key for the animals table?

Comment: location_cost table only has 2 columns: location and costs. animals table has the following columns: animalid, size, color, birthdate, weight, location, location_cost (this needs to be updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update only the rows in `animals` that have a matching `location` in `location_costs` then use this syntax:

```
UPDATE animals
SET location_cost = location_costs.costs
FROM location_costs
WHERE location_costs.location = animals.location;
```

If you want to update all the rows of `animals` (even the rows without a a matching `location` in `location_costs` will be updated to `null`), then use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE animals
SET location_cost = (
  SELECT location_costs.costs 
  FROM location_costs 
  WHERE location_costs.location = animals.location
);
```

Comment: the first code you recommended worked! location values under animals table has matching values for location under locations_cost hence it did not return any null values. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If animalid is a column with unique values, try using an alias as follows:

```
Update animals
Set location_cost = location_costs.costs
From animals As a Left Join location_costs On (a.location = location_costs.location)
Where animals.animalid = a.animalid;
```

Comment: Getting the following error: UndefinedColumn) column "animals" of relation "animals" does not exist although animalid had unique values.

Comment: @ramsha chowdhrey I have removed the table prefix for the location_cost column in the "Set" section. Try the edited version.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Code shared by forpas is a neat solution as well.

Comment: @ramsha chowdhrey You are welcome. Please checkmark the most suitable solution.